# Error when exporting the data from FairCom c-tree database (ODBC) into MS Excel

Tags: odbc, faircom, faircom-db-sql

I'm trying to transfer the data from an old .dat file into MS Excel using the ODBC driver for FairCom c-tree database. The data is transfered to Excel, but before import I've received two warning messages and it seems like the part of the data is missing.

Does anyone knows the reason I'm getting the messages:

`"SCHEMAFieldLength: field length for column #81 is 120, which is larger than record buffer. Using length 93 instead."`

and after that:

`"WARNING! Field not found for key segment(2, 4, 1). Possible DODA problem. Check alignment.`

I've tried every option on ODBC driver. Is maybe database corrupted or I'm missing something?